# Installing an Inkscape color palette on MacOS?

Tags: inkscape

The material design color palette for Inkscape:

https://github.com/drac/Material-Design-Color-Palette-for-Inkscape

Has a location for OS X, but not for MacOS.  Anyone know where to install the palette on MacOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I found it.  We have to go to ~/Applications and right click on Inkscape and select `Show Package Contents`.

The palettes are are in `Contents/Resources/share/inkscape/palettes/`.

Comment: If you get stuck looking for a folder, all the file paths for user folders are listed in *Edit > Preferences > Input/Output > System*

Comment: The paths in the preferences mentioned by @BillyKerr are a better fit, as they will remain if you update/uninstall/reinstall the Inkscape app.